# synchronization TFVC with GIT on VSTS

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

Anyone know a synchronization solution between TFVC on premise (TFS) with GIT (VSTS cloud based)? does it possible to connecting those platform ? really need your help

Comment: If you solve synchronising a TFS-VC local workspace with a local git you can use the existing ability of both TFS-VC and git to work with a remote server to complete the process.

Comment: **But** TFS-VC and git have very different data models (consider branches) so trying to synchronise more than current state will be very hard. Why do you want to do this? Seems like an XY-Problem and you would be better asking for help on the real issue (where you see TFS-VC git sync as a solution.)

Comment: Thanks for the quick comments.. let me describe you all the situation that we r facing today. first of all we decided to move from TFS on premise into VSTS, second decision was to use with GIT as a version control, now we r in the middle of full migration between TFS<>VSTS till we finish it we have short gap until we all use pure GIT, the solution that I'm looking is just for the temporary situation to combined between those platform till we all move to GIT in VSTS. hope this give you all the big pic

Comment: any comment please ?

Comment: Moving local TFS to TFS in VSTS should preserve everything. To move a project ot Git: lock in TFS-VC (no more changes, just kept for reference) and start with no history in git. Yes it is a big bang change, but you will have changed rather than some painful mixture which is really about failing to make the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this article to migrate from TFVC to Git: [Migrate from TFVC to Git](https://www.visualstudio.com/learn/migrate-from-tfvc-to-git/)

> Requirements
>
> In order to make migrations simple, there are a number of requirements
>   on the TFVC Import tool:
>
> 1. Only a single branch is migrated. When planning your migration you should choose a new branching strategy for Git; migrating only the
>      main branch supports a topic-branch based workflow like GitFlow or
>      GitHub Flow.
> 2. A “tip migration”, importing only the latest version of the source code, is suggested. You can opt to migrate some history, up to 180
>      days, so that your team doesn’t need to refer back to TFVC as often,
>      but this is discouraged unless your history is very simple.
> 3. You do not have binary assets like images, scientific data sets, or game models in your repository. These assets should use the Git LFS
>      (Large File Support) extension, which the import tool does not
>      configure.
> 4. The imported repository cannot exceed 1GB in size.

If you do not meet these requirements, you can use the Git-TFS tool to perform the migration, or perform a manual migration.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but still i didn't got answer - if there is any way to apply 2 way sync between TFVC<>VSTS based GIT?

Comment: @Yossi No, you need to migration and to do work with new git repository.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answers :)